# Tcl/Tk GUI update

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created a Tcl/Tk GUI interface which displays data, read from a certain text file. This text file is created by a perl script.Is there a way to update GUI interface without destroying the GUI?

For now I have created a button when clicked runs a proc which does the following:

> - exec to run the perl script
> - destroy top level window
> - run exec again to reinvoke the GUI

I am hoping there might be a better way to do this. I read about

> update

but I am not sure if it can be used for external events.

Answer (score 1):

If you read "some" data in "some" widget, you only should read/write the right propertie of this particular widget.

Also, some widgets (i.e "label") as an alternative to text, get the string from a variable, updating when the variable changes.